# connecting from one docker to another using port forwarding and network=host fails

Tags: python-3.x, docker, rabbitmq, network-programming, pika

## I wrote an app in python3.7.5 that connects to RabbitMQ:

#### Using Ubuntu as the docker-machine

I am running rabbitmq with docker:
`docker run --name rabbitmq -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 --hostname rabbitmq rabbitmq:3.6.6-management`

### TEST:

- My python app connects to it via 127.0.01:5672
- Expected: connects and works
- Actual:  connects and works

#### I put the app inside docker and build and run

```
--build-arg ENVIRONMENT_NAME=develop
-t pdf-svc-image:latest .
&& docker run
-P
--env ENVIRONMENT_NAME=local
--name html-to-pdf
-v /home/mickey/dev/core/components/pdf-svc/:/html-to-pdf
--privileged
--network host
pdf-svc-image:latest bash
```

(This command line is created with pycharm)

#### When running this code (inside the docker) , I get an exception

```
return await aio_pika.connect_robust(
            "amqp://guest:guest@{host}".format(host=consts.MESSAGE_QUEUE_HOST)
        )
```

- [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5672)
- [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Help ?

Comment: I'd recommend reading through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation, even if you aren't using Compose; it has some good background information on how things generally work.  Outside of Compose you need to `docker network create` a network and run both containers on that `--network`.  Avoid host networking if possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.docker.com/network/host/,

> Note: Given that the container does not have its own IP-address when using host mode networking, port-mapping does not take effect, and the -p, --publish, -P, and --publish-all option are ignored, producing a warning instead:

I am not sure this is your case. You would login the container, and do run `ping, nslookup` to check the network connection.

Answer (score -1):

RabbitMQ container

```
  docker run --name rabbitmq \
      -p 5671:5671 -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 \
      --hostname rabbitmq \
      --network host \      # <-- Add this line, now both container see each other
      rabbitmq:3.6.6-management
```

App container

```
  docker run \
      -P \
      --env ENVIRONMENT_NAME=local \
      --name html-to-pdf \
      -v /home/mickey/dev/core/components/pdf-svc/:/html-to-pdf \
      --privileged \
      --network host \
      pdf-svc-image:latest bash
```

Then on your code you need to load your variable with `host = rabbitmq` not 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend disabling Docker's networking for simple container-to-container communications.

Comment: Yes, I said to add forgotten network. Where did you see u remove it?

Comment: `--net host` says to disable Docker's networking layer.  It may fix the immediate issue, but in the same way that running a process as root gets around permissions problems: it doesn't fix the underlying issue and can have unintended side effects.